# Creating a library in MASM while using dosbox

Tags: assembly, masm32, dosbox

I have a question, i have been given an assignment to make a static library in assembly language i.e. MASM, but all the tutorials i find on the internet are either incomplete or too hard for me to understand. I am using dosbox since i have a 64 bit windows. 
Please help step by step
Please and thank you

Comment: We help with specific questions, but doing something step-by-step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using DosBox only for running the final executable. You don't need DosBox to produce this executable, since Masm32 runs under 64 bit Windows. But the `lib.exe` shipped with Masm32 doesn't produce a OMF-Library suitable for `link16.exe`. So you have to get a `lib.exe` which "speaks" OMF, e.g. the `lib.exe` by DigitalMars (http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/lib.html).

Example:

**main.asm:**

```
.MODEL small

.code
EXTERN sub1:NEAR
main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    call sub1

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
main ENDP

.stack 1000h

END main
```

**function.asm:**

```
.MODEL small

.data
    text db "This is sub1.",13,10,"$"

.code
sub1 PROC
    push ax
    push dx

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, OFFSET text
    int 21h

    pop dx
    pop ax
    ret
sub1 ENDP

END
```

**build.cmd:**

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PATH=C:\masm32\bin

ml.exe /c function.asm
ml.exe /c main.asm

<Path to DigitalMars>\dm\bin\lib.exe -c main.lib main.obj function.obj
link16.exe main.lib ;
```

Build it in a console of Windows and run `main.exe` in DosBox.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, i am going to try this now.

Comment: the lib.exe file on this website digital mars is not downloadable. my understanding of your explanation tells me that i cant make the final library without that.lib file, can you give me the download link?

Comment: @user3621489: My link points to the documentation. But the download link of the whole C++ suite (with lib.exe) is on the same domain: <http://ftp.digitalmars.com/Digital_Mars_C++/Patch/dm857c.zip>. BTW: this was the first one I found, eventually there are more "libberers" out there :-)

Comment: found it, made the lib file.
You sir are a genius.

One more thing. 
I am trying to call this library into my c program , but c takes libraries of .dll or .h extentions. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3621489: `.lib` files are for the linker, so you must set an appropriate linker option. Attention: This 16 bit '.lib' matches **only** a 16 bit Compiler and Linker ('.dll' smells of 32 or 64 bit) . The rest is stuff for a new question (don't forget to tell compiler and sample codes).