# How do i make a library of external assembly files?

Tags: assembly, dos

Objective:
To link my library .inc files with my main .asm program. Ex **(in c-like)**:

```
MainTestingProgram.c        /bin/
                          |
                          [ getChar.h ]
                          [ getChar.c ]
```

I've tried googling and searching everywhere, but i cannot get a good enough answer to this. My MainTestingProgram.asm looks like this:

```
extern /bin/getChar.inc

.model  small
.stack  100h

.data

.code
main    proc
        mov     ax,@data
        mov     ds,ax

        mov     ax,5
        call    getChar

        mov     ax,4C00h
        int     21h
main    endp
end     main
```

and then my subroutine file getChar.inc would like like this:

```
getChar proc
        mov     ah,01h
        int     21h
        ret
getChar endp
```

This is in dos, so it is 16 bit format. Please no answers that pertain to another bit format. You may need a windows98 virtual machine too.

Comment: I gather from the code that you are using MASM?

Comment: Consider looking at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23579133/3857942) which appears to be a similar question (And is MASM related with 16-bit code / 16-bit linker). Uou'll need to download a different `lib.exe` (a link to one is provided in the answer) that will allow you to build a 16-bit library of 16-bit modules (objects)